# C pointers vs. Objective-C pointers

Tags: c, objective-c, pointers

I'm coming from an Objective-C background and am trying to expand my knowledge in C.  One thing has me confused, however, and that's the difference between pointers in C and Obj-C.  As you can see in the examples below, things seem to behave a bit differently between both languages, and I was wondering if you could help explain why?

**C code works fine:**

```
void myFunction()
{
    int x, *pointerX; 
    pointerX = &x;
    *pointerX = 5;

    // Prints: "x is 5"
    printf("x is: %i", x);
}
```

**Obj-C code fails:**

```
- (void)myMethod
{
    NSString *string = @"Caramel coffee", *stringPointer;
    stringPointer = &string;                    // Warning:   Assignemnt from incompatible pointer type
    *stringPointer = @"Chocolate milkshake";    // Exception: Incompatible types in assignment

    NSLog(@"string is: %@", string);
}
```

**Question:**  Why can't I assign stringPointer to the memory address of string (`stringPointer = &string;`), and why am I able to perform `*pointerX = 5;` under C, but I can't perform `*stringPointer = @"Chocolate milkshake";` under Objective-C?

I realize that Obj-C deals with objects and C doesn't, but I can't seem to figure out the behind-the-scenes details as to why it doesn't work in Obj-C.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: Are you trying to figure out the C part or the Objective-C part? From your question it looks like you want to learn C but you are writing Objective-C code that looks like C ...

Comment: The C part. Sorry about the confusion. My background is I've read some Objective-C books, and am now reading C books. What got me confused was how pointers worked in C, which seemed to be a bit different (even though Obj-C is built on top of C).

Comment: I'm quite sure the pointers work the same in C and Objective-C, I think you are getting confused when using Cocoa classes without understanding how to use them. The easiest thing is to look for examples to see how Cocoa classes are generally used that would clear up the problems, as I said the issue might be with class tree that is hidden behind interface classes that you are dealing with.

Comment: Great stefanB, I think you're probably right.  I'll definitely take a peek at some more Cocoa examples.  Thanks so much!  :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your first example, `x` and `pointerX` have different types (`(int)` and `(int *)` respectively).  In your second example, `string` and `stringPointer` have the *same* type (`NSString *`).  Try instead:

```
NSString *string = @"Caramel coffee", **stringPointer;
```

Answer (score 11):

Your `NSString *string` is itself a pointer. Therefore, in order to point to it, you need to declare `stringPointer` as a pointer to a pointer. That is, declare `stringPointer` like this:

```
NSString **stringPointer;
```

Then everything should work. Note that the same pointer semantics apply in C and Objective-C.

Answer (score 5):

The thing is that when you create an object, you actually always manipulate it through a pointer assigned to it, hence (NSString *).

Try doing the same thing in C (working with a string), perhaps it becomes clearer:

```
void myFunction()
{
    char *string = "this is a C string!";
    char **ptr=&string;


    // Prints: "this is a c string"
    printf("ptr points to %s: \n",  *ptr);
}
```

As you can see, pointers work in exactly the same way as they do in objective-c. Bare in mind that there are very few primitives in objective-c (int is the most obvious one). Most of the time you are creating a pointer of type object X (say NSString), and then allocating a chunk of memory (through [[Object alloc] init]) and assigining the start address of that chunk to your pointer. Exactly the same as we've done in C with our string.

Answer (score 3):

`&string` has type `NSString **`, whereas `stringPointer` has type `NSString *`, thus the warning.
Then you try to assign an instance of NSString (with type `NSString *`) to a variable of type `NSString`, thus the error.

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to define each variable on its own line. The when you rewrite your initial objective-с code like

```
NSString* string = @"Caramel coffee";
NSString* stringPointer;
```

many things become clear.

Comment: -1 Still doesn't fix the problem, since the pointer types are incompatible.

Comment: @Quinn: at a moment when a wrote my message the problem was already solved. May be it's better to wright such style related messages in comments, but then there is no ability for code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The question is - are your strings const or not?
The first example would probably work.
Even in non-objective C compilers, literal strings can be placed in const memory via linker / compiler options.

On this line:
stringPointer = &string; 
You are copying the address of the pointer into the string poitner.  Clearly incompatible.

And on this line:
*stringPointer = @"Chocolate milkshake";

You are trying to write a string into the pointer (the pointer is a 4 byte address).  Not a good idea to copy a whole string on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

**What are you trying to do?**

Not sure if it will work as you intended.

**You seem to be taking concepts from C and apply it to Cocoa classes, I thought you were learning C. Have you seen anywhere in Objective-C code taking address of an object?**

Cocoa classes are implemented using `Class clusters` which mean that they share the same interface but you will get specific extended class which you manipulate.

In your case you are taking address of possibly class that extends `NSString` and assign it to pointer to `NSString`.

Example:

```
NSString * str = @"Caramel coffee";
NSString * str2 = [NSString stringWithString:@"all"];

NSLog(@"%@", [[str class] className]);
NSLog(@"%@", [[str class] className]);
```

Output (GNUStep linux):

```
2009-12-08 10:49:29.149 x[25446] GSCInlineString
2009-12-08 10:49:29.149 x[25446] NSConstantString
```

... apart from the obvious pointer definition problems pointed out by others.

Comment: The NSError pattern is probably the most common case where we take the address of an object in Objective-C: "NSError *error; [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"foo" error:&error];

Comment: Yes but we pass a address of local variable into a method because we expect value returned. But you would not generally see stuff like `NSString * str = &someotherNSStringObject;`